# Count entries of specific object property name within current index

Tags: javascript, properties, count

**How would I efficiently go about counting the .length of a specific object property within a current object index?**

Would I need to iterate through each `content.item` index and then iterate through `content.item.itemSettings.item.monsters` and on the way do a "manual" countup?

In the below im trying to count a specific property for each 
`content.item` where the property im trying to count is "monsters":

```
content.item.itemSettings.item.monsters
```

- The first (index) count [0] of content.item would be expected to be = 4
- The second (index) count [1] of content.item would be expected to be = 3

```js
var content = {
  item: [{
      mainId: 50,

      itemSettings: {
        item: [{
            level: 1,

            monsters: [{
                name: 'monster 1',

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: 'blue',
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 70,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 30,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
              {
                name: 'monster 2',

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: 'pink',
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 20,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 90,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            level: 1,

            monsters: [{
                name: 'monster 3',

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: 'gray',
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 50,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 55,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
              {
                name: 'monster 4',

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: 'red',
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 20,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 100,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
            ]
          },
        ] //mainId
      }, //itemSettings
    }, //content.item

    //NEW
    {
      mainId: 60,

      itemSettings: {
        item: [{
            level: 2,

            monsters: [{
                name: 'monster 2-1',

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: 'blue',
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 70,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 30,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
              {
                name: 'monster 2-2',

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: 'pink',
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 20,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 90,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            level: 2,

            monsters: [{
              name: 'monster 2-3',

              item: [{
                innerLabel: 'gray',
                year: [{
                    yearVal: 2016,
                    yearStat: 50,
                  },
                  {
                    yearVal: 2012,
                    yearStat: 55,
                  }
                ]
              }]
            }, ]
          },
        ] //mainId
      }, //itemSettings
    }, //content.item

  ]
}; //content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) for this. (If you don't understand anything in the code, please ask)

```js
var length = content.item.reduce((sum, value) => {
  return sum + Object.values(value.itemSettings.item).reduce((isum, ivalue) => {
    return isum + ivalue.monsters.length;
  }, 0);
}, 0);
```

**Working code:**

```js
var content = {
  item: [
    {
      mainId: 50,
      itemSettings: {
        item: [{
            level: 1,

            monsters: [{
                name: "monster 1",

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: "blue",
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 70,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 30,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
              {
                name: "monster 2",

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: "pink",
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 20,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 90,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            level: 1,

            monsters: [{
                name: "monster 3",

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: "gray",
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 50,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 55,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
              {
                name: "monster 4",

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: "red",
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 20,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 100,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
    },
   {
      mainId: 60,

      itemSettings: {
        item: [{
            level: 2,

            monsters: [{
                name: "monster 2-1",

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: "blue",
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 70,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 30,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
              {
                name: "monster 2-2",

                item: [{
                  innerLabel: "pink",
                  year: [{
                      yearVal: 2016,
                      yearStat: 20,
                    },
                    {
                      yearVal: 2012,
                      yearStat: 90,
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            level: 2,

            monsters: [{
              name: "monster 2-3",

              item: [{
                innerLabel: "gray",
                year: [{
                    yearVal: 2016,
                    yearStat: 50,
                  },
                  {
                    yearVal: 2012,
                    yearStat: 55,
                  }
                ]
              }]
            }, ]
          },
        ]
      },
    }
  ]
};

var length = content.item.reduce((sum, value) => {
    return sum + Object.values(value.itemSettings.item).reduce((isum, ivalue) => {
      return isum + ivalue.monsters.length;
    }, 0);
}, 0);

console.log(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the length of each index separately, you can use the following code:

```
content.item.map(item =>
  item.itemSettings.item.reduce((count, itemInner) =>
    count + itemInner.monsters.length, 0
  )
);
```

Output: `[4, 3]`